# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper is named BuildUser in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, groovy, pipeline

I preparing script in Jenkins as below where I getting error while build job. This job is send email to user for `input` for next step.

```
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper is named BuildUser
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:549)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:473)
    ...
    ...
```

Version :

```
$ java --version
 openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20

jenkins : 2.277.3
```

Pipeline code:

```
def user
node {
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
user = env.BUILD_USER_ID
}

emailext mimeType: 'text/html',
             subject: "[Jenkins]${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             to: "user@xxx.com",
             body: '''<a href="${BUILD_URL}input">click to approve</a>'''
}

pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('deploy') {
        input {
            message "Should we continue?"
            ok "Yes"
        }
        when {
            expression { user == 'hardCodeApproverJenkinsId'}
        }
        steps {
            sh "echo 'describe your deployment' "
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Can anyone please review this, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the [Build User Vars Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/)? This plugin provides the "BuildUser" class.